# Exibir muitos elementos no DOM pode prejudicar a performance?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Eu gosto muito de utilizar bibliotecas como `Vue` e `AngularJs` e a minha implementação favorita era fazer *Infinite Scroll* (ou carregamento por demanda). Quer dizer, carrego inicialmente 15 registros via ajax. Se o usuário rola a página, carrega mais 15, e assim até acabar os registros, e montando os elementos no DOM de acordo com isso.

Eu fico me perguntando se essa operação pode causar algum problema de performance quanto a memória ou mesmo a navegação (causando travamentos, por exemplo).

Não quero entrar em discussões sobre o Watcher do Angular, ng-repeat e afins, mas sim saber especificamente sobre o DOM.

Ter muitos elementos no DOM poderia prejudicar a performance?

Por exemplo, se eu faço um infinite scroll na minha página, e ele gerar umas 10.000 divs, isso poderia impactar no desempenho da minha página?

Existe alguma recomendação a respeito disso?

Exemplo:

```js
var listElm = document.querySelector('#infinite-list');


var nextItem = 1;
var loadMore = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = 'Item ' + nextItem++;
    listElm.appendChild(item);
  }
}


listElm.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (listElm.scrollTop + listElm.clientHeight >= listElm.scrollHeight) {
    loadMore();
  }
});


loadMore();
```

```css
#infinite-list {
  /* We need to limit the height and show a scrollbar */
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;

  /* Optional, only to check that it works with margin/padding */
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

/* Optional eye candy below: */
li {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul id='infinite-list'>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pode sim, é que estou sem tempo para responder explicando como ocorre o processo de renderização, mas pode sim consumir muito, no entanto existem estratégias para evitar isso, como desanexar temporariamente os elementos, claro que é um ganho relativo e é algo complicado de aplicar, ainda mais que ao injetar novamente certos eventos podem ser disparados, claro que isso dá para resolver. Também existe a questão do *GC* e do elemento mesmo estando desanexado ainda pode estar referenciado em alguma variavel/objeto, o que geralmente é problema de muitos frameworks.

Comment: Um processo que evita uso desnecessário de processamento/memória no caso de listas muito grandes é o chamado **Virtual List**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Ter muitos elementos no DOM poderia prejudicar a performance?

Sim, e vamos analisar dois aspectos:

- **memória** - quanto mais elementos o DOM tiver, obviamente mais memória irá consumir, abaixo coloquei duas imagens para ilustrar, mas isso em geral não deve ser um grande problema em *desktops*, mas em dispositivos pode ser, onde a memória é em geral menor.
- **processamento** - aqui está o aspecto que mais impacta. Apenas carregar conteúdo e ir exibindo não é o maior problema, mas sim quando você precisa acessar o DOM e por exemplo procurar um elemento e alterá-lo. Isso pode travar o motor do navegador ao processar `Javascript` dependendo do tamanho do DOM.
  Além disso, partindo da ideia que seu DOM tem muitos nós e elementos, pode-se também pensar na ideia que vá excluir nós/elementos. Guardar referências para elementos pode gerar *memory leaks* (aqui uma ótima leitura sobre isso: [Gerenciamento de memória no Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)), o que pode gerar problemas de performance bem sérios.

### Por exemplo, se eu faço um infinite scroll na minha página, e ele gerar umas 10.000 divs, isso poderia impactar no desempenho da minha página?

Com certeza sim, especialmente se o conteúdo adicionado não o for de maneira otimizada, ou ainda se houver alteração do conteúdo.
No seu exemplo de código é fácil de observar isso:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = 'Item ' + nextItem++;
    listElm.appendChild(item);
  }
```

O melhor seria adicionar todos os elementos a uma nova estrutura, que ainda não esteja no DOM e depois, somente ao final, adicionar tudo ao DOM, dessa maneira:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = 'Item ' + nextItem++;
    frag.appendChild(item);
  }
listElm.appendChild(frag);
```

Sobre o uso de memória, executando o seu *snippet*, veja o consumo de memória com nenhum elemento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E com 100000+ elementos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, praticamento dobrou, então dependendo da memória disponível no equipamento do cliente, o tamanho do DOM fará diferença.

### Existe alguma recomendação a respeito disso?

Existem várias coisas que podem ser feitas para melhorar a performance:

- ter poucos nós/elementos no DOM (meio óbvio);
- manipular o DOM em bloco, como no exemplo de código acima;
- evitar referências para nós/elementos em variáveis globais, especialmente elementos que podem ser excluídos, para não prejudicar
  o trabalho do garbage collector;
- quando possível, teste com `Javascript` puro no lugar de *frameworks*. Aqui uma experiência minha: versões mais antigas do `JQuery` tem problemas ao validar um grande número de campos,
  deixando extremamente lento o navegador. Tive um formulário com pouco
  mais de 500 inputs que gerava uma lentidão de quase 60s para validar.
  Isso foi corrigido posteriormente, mas uma validação pura foi muito
  mais eficiente;

Existem várias outras dicas, mas me limitei aqui a algumas pensando no foco da pergunta, qualquer contribuição será muito bem vinda.

Comment: Vou abrir recompensa nessa pergunta também. Estou apenas esperar as outras acabarem.

Comment: Legal, isso chama mais respostas :)

Comment: Muito bacana sua resposta completa, Ricardo. Já passei por alguns problemas parecidos, em que tentei manipular alguns elementos DOMs dentre muitos outros nós já impressos, e tive grave problema de performance. Manipular o que puder direto no "VanillaJS" foi o que me trouxe mais perfomance.

Comment: @PedroFerreira, a ideia por trás do `reactjs` é melhorar isso: basicamente ele processa uma copia do dom em memória e só atualiza o necessário de uma vez, é uma boa alternativa

Comment: @RicardoPontual, interessante, fica claro que vai resultar numa melhora de performance. Acho que datagrids fica bem evidente. Obrigado pela dica.